# Detect monitor off on Win7

Tags: windows-7, monitor, power-management

Win7-based kiosk, clerk-accessible switch powers off the monitor, my task is to detect this and either do an orderly shutdown or a shutdown/reboot or nothing at all, based on other factors. If I had any input on the physical design I'd do things differently, but ... this is what I have to work with. I've found a few different methods which are supposed to detect that the monitor is powered off, but none of them have worked. I'd prefer to be sent an event rather than be polling once/second.

1. Screen.AllScreens.Length continues to return 1 even when the monitor is powered off.
2. SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged does not get invoked.
3. SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged does not get invoked.
4. RegisterPowerSettingNotification with GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS does not result in any messages (but later I found something which lead me to think that GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS isn't supported until Windows 8 - is that correct?).
5. RegisterPowerSettingNotification with GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON gives me one message when I start but does not give a WM_POWERBROADCAST message when the monitor is powered off (nor when the monitor is powered back on). I had high hopes for this because MS doc actually says "The display is turned on or off, either 
   **by the user** or by the system's screen-blanking function." This is within the "Mobile PC" section and we are a Desktop version of the OS, so maybe it doesn't apply to us?

Any other ideas for detecting that the monitor has been switched off? Or common gotchas which make it look like it's not working which may be affecting my tests?

Do I have to figure out how to speak VESA DDC (from C#)? I guess all I'd have to figure out is how to send a valid command - any response at all means the monitor is on, no response means it is off.